# My Ionic capacitor plugin I developed crashes my app on android

Tags: android, ionic-framework, plugins, capacitor

I developed a very simple ionic capacitor plugin. I used the stock standard echo method without changing a thing at it works in my app. I call the plugin and get an echo back.
I then imported the cloudpossdk-1.5.2.aar which I need for my Point of Sale terminal.
As soon as I implement this my app crashes on load.
When I run the `cloudpossdk-1.5.2.aar` as a stand alone app and not as a plugin it works fine.
I think it's a permissions issue. The app which works (not as a plugin) I gave it permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CLOUDPOS_LED" />`
I am stugling to work out how to debug this.
Thanks in advance

```
package com.rts.plugins.hardwareapi;

import com.getcapacitor.JSObject;
import com.getcapacitor.Plugin;
import com.getcapacitor.PluginCall;
import com.getcapacitor.PluginMethod;
import com.getcapacitor.annotation.CapacitorPlugin;

import com.cloudpos.DeviceException;
import com.cloudpos.POSTerminal;
import com.cloudpos.led.LEDDevice;


@CapacitorPlugin(name = "hardwareapi")
public class hardwareapiPlugin extends Plugin {

    private hardwareapi implementation = new hardwareapi();

    @PluginMethod
    public void echo(PluginCall call) {

      LEDDevice lEDDevice =
        (LEDDevice) POSTerminal.getInstance(getContext()).getDevice("cloudpos.device.led");
      try {
        lEDDevice.open();
        lEDDevice.turnOff();
      } catch (DeviceException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }


        String value = call.getString("value");
        JSObject ret = new JSObject();
        ret.put("value", implementation.echo(value));
        call.resolve(ret);
    }
}
```

So I have pulled in the cloudpossdk.aar file into my android ionic plugin but if I use implementation in the build.gradle I cannot compile and get this error

*Direct local .aar file dependencies are not supported when building an AAR. The resulting AAR would be broken because the classes and Android resources from any local .aar file*

I found that I can change it to compileOnly then my project builds.

This is part of build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation project(':capacitor-android')
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$androidxAppCompatVersion"
    compileOnly files('src/libs/cloudpossdk-1.5.2.aar')
    testImplementation "junit:junit:$junitVersion"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.ext:junit:$androidxJunitVersion"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:$androidxEspressoCoreVersion"
}
```

I found this error below which I am wondering if not including the cloudpos lib when building apk

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.cloudpos.POSTerminal" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/io.ionic.starter-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/io.ionic.starter-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
```

Comment: Whats the crash? there should be a log of it

Comment: Serious error executing plugin.
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/cloudpos/POSTerminal

Comment: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.cloudpos.POSTerminal" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/io.ionic.starter-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/io.ionic.starter-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

I got it working but believe its a hack.
I brought the `.aar` into my capacitor plugin but I also brought it into my app which is consuming the plugin.
Surely a plugin is just that, include it and use it.

Anyway, it solves the problem for me.